# call action from valuechanged method Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to call a action which is in the separate class.

```
public class ShowMPCAction extends AbstractAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // action code
    }

}
```

from the class

```
public class PLListSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // some code
        if (!lsm.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            // from here I want to call the action which is in the class ShowMPCAction
        }
    }
```

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to create a dummy `JButton` and call it's click event like this.

In your `public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {` method,

```
javax.swing.JButton jb = new javax.swing.JButton(new ShowMPCAction());
jb.doClick();
```

Comment: I want to call this action on selecting row from JTable

Comment: Upon selecting row, I assume `valueChanged` method is getting called. There I am forcefully activating the `ShowMPCAction` by creating dummy button.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to inject ShowMPCAction into PL ListSelectionListener, for example via constructor

Answer (score -1):

You could just create an instance of ShowMPCAction and call the method directly.

```
ShowMPCAction object = new ShowMPCAction();
object.actionPerformed(e);
```

Is this what your looking for?

Comment: It will just become a method call not a control event.

Comment: I didn't read anywhere about control event... Just call the action was the question...

Comment: I guess `call a action` refers to a control event.